# How do I find a connected sub-graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a network but this network is not connected. I want to know how I can find a biggest connected graph in this network?

Comment: What does this have to do with C++? Are you working with something in particular? Are you stuck somewhere? Please include all relevant details. In its current form this question is not good/clear enough.

Comment: It's very unclear what you want to do. Also your question it's labelled C++, but you say something about network, graph etc.

Comment: Everyone this is OP's first question. Please try to improve the question before downvoting and provide some guidance

Comment: @nastaranlotfi please try to **add** relevant tags to get better answers(sorry for the silly mistake in my previous comment).

Comment: Flood fill algorithm might help. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill

Answer (score 1):

To compute the connected component that a node belongs to, simply run any kind of graph search algorithm for instance [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

To solve your problem iterate over all nodes in the network and do the following:

1. If the given node has been added to a component go to the next node(continue the iteration)
2. If the node has not been added to a component, run any graph search(e.g. BFS as suggested above) and mark all visited nodes as belonging to the same component.
3. Select the maximum-sized component as constructed in step 2 above.

Answer (score 0):

Let the graph be a[n][n], with a[i][j]=1 if i,j are connected .

The you can the do following .

```
count=0;/global


void dfs(int i)
{

int k;
for(k=0;k<n;k++)
    if(A[i][k]==1 && !visited[k])
    {
        count++;
        visited[k]=1;
        dfs(k);
    }
}
for(i=0; i < n;i++)
    {
        if(!visited[i])
        {
            count=1;
            visited[i]=1;
            dfs(i);
                            // map i with count .. here

        }
    }
```

So once you have done mapping count of nodes in a network with one of its node .

All you need to do now is to find the node with max count in your map .

So you will get the key , which is a node of big network with count map(i) .

Make all nodes visited to 0 and apply dfs(i) again you can get whole network connected with

i and you have the count anyways .

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is to use [union-find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure):

```
S = array filled with 1s (|V| elements)

for each edge (u,v) in E:
    if find_set(u) != find_set(v):
        sum = S[find_set(u)] + S[find_set(v)]
        S[find_set(v)] = sum
        S[find_set(u)] = sum
        union_set(u, v)
```

At the end, S[find_set(u)] will be the size of the connected component which node u belongs to. To find the maximum one, you just need the find max(S).

Since both find_set and union_set are simple to implement (2 lines of C++ each), I find this method way cleaner than a DFS or BFS.